How to enable insecure local host?
Chrome must relaunch after I enable Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost in chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost of the Chrom emulator from Android Studio. But this setting always back to the default when I run Chrom with my project again. How to enable it?
tried temporary -unexpire -flags-m118 & m117

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
